# Time complexity for a sublist in Python

Tags: python, performance, list, big-o, sublist

In Python, what is the time complexity when we create a sublist from an existing list?

For example, here data is the name of our existing list and list1 is our sublist created by slicing data.

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6..100,...1000....,10^6] 
list1 = data[101:10^6]
```

What is the running time for creating list1?

```
Is it O(10^6) i.e.O(N), or O(1)?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting a list slice in python is `O(M - N)` / `O(10^6 - 101)`

[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) you can check  python list operations time complexity

By underneath, python lists are represented like arrays. So, you can iterate starting on some index(N) and stopping in another one(M)