# Time complexity for lookup in dictionary.values() lists vs sets

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, hashmap, big-o

In Python, we know that looking up a key in a dictionary takes O(1) run time, but what is the run time to look up in the dictionary.values() ?

```
dictionary = {'a':[66,77,88], 'b':[99,100]}
key = 'a'
if key in dictionary: # takes O(1) run time 

number = '99'
if number in dictionary.values():  # What is the run time here?
```

Edit #1: The values for the keys could be either lists or sets. Many folks have responded that if the values are lists the run time is O(1).

Will it be O(N) if values are sets?

```
dictionary = {'a':(66,77,88), 'b':(99,100)}
number = '99'
if number in dictionary.values():  # What is the run time here?
```

Comment: `O(n)` of course as you at worst case have to look at every value. If using python2 just calling `.values()` alone creates a list of all values.

Comment: O(n). It has read all the values and compare with each of them. BTW, it won't work that way if you have lists as values.

Comment: basically it's `O(n)`. But if you want to look up in such values that are lists it won't be O(n) any more.

Comment: Typically it is of O(n), as it it is just passing through a list

Comment: You also asked a question 2 days ago that gave you the complexity for all python operations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338520/time-complexity-for-a-sublist-in-python

Comment: This question was closed wrongly because dict.values() does not return a list but a dictionary view. I believe it's still O(n) because values views are not set-like, in contrast to keys views. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let be `x in s` the operation which searches in a list, {x=item , s=list}

The average case - assuming parameters generated uniformly at random - for such operation will be O(n)

For more info about time complexity, here's the [official link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: dict.values does not return a list though, it returns a view. In this case, values views are not set-like. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects