# what is time complexity of python Dictionary.values()?

Tags: python

I have referred to this page but it shows **Dict.keys()'s** time complexity.
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

This sheet also shows the same https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/complexity-cheat-sheet-for-python-operations/

[Time complexity for lookup in dictionary.values() lists vs sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380593/time-complexity-for-lookup-in-dictionary-values-lists-vs-sets)
In this case, it searches for each key's `list` so it didn't help me.
Because in my case, all Dict's values will be a single integer.

Q(1): Is it O(1) or O(n) for **Dict.values()**?

```
Dict = {1:10,2:20,3:30,4:40}
if 10 in Dict.values():
    print("YES")
```

Q(2): In python is it possible to get key by supplying value?[if the supplied value comes multiple times in Dict.values() I would like to get all corresponding keys]

```
Dict = {1:10,2:20,3:30,4:40}
value = 20
```

I want to find key=2 by this value. Is it possible with O(1), because in O(n) I have to check for all key's value!!!

Comment: I think both your examples are `O(n)`, but the call itself `dict.values()` is `O(1)` due to delayed execution.

Comment: If you want to test if a value is present, and get the key associated with a value, then your dictionary is back-to-front. Make it `{10: 1, 20: 2, 30: 3, 40: 4}` instead.

Comment: @RoyCohen First you said it is O(n) and then you said Dict.values() is O(1) because of delayed execution[Then what should I assume? O(1) or O(n)?]

Comment: @kaya3 Yeah that's true. So I assume, answer is no for my case.

Comment: @AayushScet The call `dict.values()` itself is `O(1)`, but when you use the object returned by `dict.values()` it's usually `O(n)` (depends on what you're doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q(1)：<del>I think it is O(1)</del>

edit:I was wrong.It is O(n).Thanks to @Roy Cohen and @kaya3.

test code:

```
import timeit
def timeis(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        start =  timeit.default_timer()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end =  timeit.default_timer()
        print(func.__name__, end-start)
        return result
    return wrap

import random
@timeis
def dict_values_test(dic,value):
    return value in dic.values()

tiny_dic = {i : 10*i for i in range(1000)}
value = random.randint(1,1000)
dict_values_test(tiny_dic,value)
small_dic = {i : 10*i for i in range(1000000)}
value = random.randint(1,1000000)
dict_values_test(small_dic,value)
big_dic = {i : 10*i for i in range(100000000)}
value = random.randint(1,100000000)
dict_values_test(big_dic,value)
```

result:

```
dict_values_test 2.580000000002025e-05
dict_values_test 0.015847600000000073
dict_values_test 1.4836825999999999
```

Q(2):

code:

```
def find_key_by_value(dic,find_value):
    return [k for k,v in dic.items() if v == find_value]
        
dic = {1:10,2:20,3:30,4:40,5:40}
print(find_key_by_value(dic,40))
```

result:

```
[4, 5]
```

Comment: The `1000` is always the 100th value in the dict. The fact that the times are all 0 means that the algorithm shortcircuts, not that it's `O(1)`.

Comment: Please use `timeit`, not `time`, for benchmarking Python code, especially single operations.